# WPF ComboBox IsEnable when using custom DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

Here it's the following. I want to disable a combo box.

In some scenarios in a window I just set `SelectedItem` from `ViewModel` to something and don't allowing the user to change it. But in some cases I want to allow.

**This one works perfectly when changing `ComboBoxIsEnabled` property in VM.**

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyColletionView, Mode=OneWay}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          IsEnabled="{Binding MyComboBoxIsEnabled}"/>
```

**After changing `ComboBox.ItemTemplate` the `IsEnable` property not reacting anymore. In short, I can't disable the `ComboBox`.**

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyColletionView, Mode=OneWay}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          IsEnabled="{Binding MyComboBoxIsEnabled}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CustomerConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

I don't want to disable the `ComboBoxItem`, I want to disable the `ComboBox` itsef.

Any suggestions, or someone facing the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ComboBox Height="20" Width="200" IsEnabled="True" Margin="38,38,1682,1022" ItemsSource="{Binding SourceData}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

I write a sample as you described.but I didnot use mvvm.I want to prove that there is no relationship in IsEnable and ItemTemplate.
you can trace this issue from tips as follow.

1. Watch Output window in VisualStudio.There may be some exception.
2. replace mvvm with codebehind and try.

Comment: Found the issue. I used the quick definitions and never looked the return typo!

private bool _customerIsEnabled = true;
public bool CustomerIsEnabled
{
   get { return _customerIsEnabled = true; }
   set { SetProperty(ref _customerIsEnabled, value); }
}